# Drawing a graphical representation or graph of links between friends

Tags: facebook, graph

I am looking out for a open source API(preferably in PHP) through which I can draw a graphical representation or a graphical structure to represent the network of friends in Facebook(Nodes being the friends).

Any of you have come across this before? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Are you asking how to draw a graph or how to retrieve friends data?

Answer (score 1):

Give Graphviz a try. There's a PHP wrapper available at http://pear.php.net/package/Image_GraphViz/docs/latest/GraphViz/Image_GraphViz.html

Comment: I was thinking there should be some inbuilt facebook api or package to fetch these stuff?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Are you asking for a way to draw a representation of the node-edge data or for a way to gather the node-edge data itself?

Comment: I am sorry for not making it clear. I am looking out for a way to draw a graph to show the relationship between friends in Facebook. Example: A is a friend of B and B is a friend of C, then first level graph of A should should show B, second level should show C and so on....